# Simplify a cleaning process

Tags: r

I have a data frame I want to clean. There is a column price that contains outliers and I want to clean it using the quantile 85, but not measured for the entire dataframe, but for each group of records that belongs to the same "neighbourghood_group".

I am doing one by one. First i create a new dataframe (df.Barajas) from the original one (df.imp), filtering it by the neighbourhood_group i want to use to calculate the quantile. Then I calculate the quantile for the specific neighbourhood_group and then I drop the rows from the original file that meet the conditions.

```
df.Barajas <- df.imp[df.imp$neighbourhood_group=="Barajas",]

Barajas.quantile <- quantile(df.Barajas$price, probs=c(.85), na.rm=T)

df.imp <- df.imp[!df.imp$neighbourhood=="Barajas" & df.imp$price<Barajas.quantile,]
```

But there are 21 different neighbourhood_groups so I would have to write 63 lines of code. How could I simplify this?

Thanks in advance,
Gabriel

Comment: Please make your question reproducible by including your data as an object in the question. Paste the data frame into the question with `dput(df)`. This makes it easier for others to test and verify solutions. [MRE] provides guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Pending a reproducible example as requested by @Peter, you can probably do:

```
library(tidyverse)
df_new <- df_imp %>%
  group_by(neighbourhood_group) %>%
  filter(price < quantile(price, probs = c(0.85), na.rm = TRUE))
  ungroup()
```